# Emacs folding mode error

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs, emacs23

I want to be able to use the emacs folding mode provided by folding.el from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode

I put the following in my .emacs file:

```
(setq load-path (cons (concat (getenv "HOME") "/.emacs.d") load-path))
(load "folding")
(folding-mode-add-find-file-hook)
(folding-add-to-marks-list 'latex-mode   "%{"  "%}"  nil t)
```

Then, when I select a region and run

```
M-x folding-fold-region
```

I get the error

```
Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, nil
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems :

- you don't have to re-declare marks for latex-mode as this is already done in [folder.el line 4411](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs-tiny-tools.git/tree/lisp/other/folding.el?h=devel#n4411). Thus you should remove the line `(folding-add-to-marks-list 'latex-mode   "%{"  "%}"  nil t)`
- You get the error `Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, nil` when the `folder-mode` is not enabled. Adding the line `(folding-mode-add-find-file-hook)` is not enough to open a file in `folder-mode` by default. To open in `folder-mode`, you should also place the `folded-file` local variable in the first line of the file you want to open, for example, in lisp :

```
;; -*- folded-file: t; -*-
```

With this local variable, and the `(folding-mode-add-find-file-hook)` command in your `.emacs` the `folder-mode` is enabled and you don't have problem anymore when calling `folding-fold-region` on a region.

Do a <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `folding-mode-add-find-file-hook` <kbd>RET</kbd> to have the explanation of this mechanism.